# How to add SageMath 9.4 kernel in Jupyter notebook

Tags: jupyter-notebook, sage

[image]

[image]

I have installed SageMath 9.4, but I could not lunch it in my terminal. When I type `sage` it said `zsh: command not found: sage` then I tried

```
alias sage='/Applications/SageMath-9-4.app'
```

and type `sage` again it said

```
zsh: permission denied: /Applications/SageMath-9-4.app
```

next I tried to add permission on that SageMath file. I `cd` to `Applications` file and type

```
chmod +x ./SageMath-9-4.app
```

Nothing happened.

I tried these to add sage in my Jupyter notebook directly

```
sudo jupyter kernelspec install /Applications/SageMath-9-4.app

jupyter kernelspec install --user /Applications/SageMath-9-4.app
```

They didn't work.

by the way:

```
jupyter kernelspec list
Available kernels:
  python3    /Applications/anaconda3/share/jupyter/kernels/python3
```

I googled these operations, but they didn't work on me. what should I do?

I want to lunch Sage in terminal when I type `sage` and I want to select kernel whenever I use Jupyter notebook.

The only way I can lunch SageMath is double click the App icon, and there will be a pop-out window
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I got it on MacOS with SageMath 9.5 mac app install from homebrew.

```
(base) ➜  ~ sage -sh -c 'ls -d $SAGE_VENV/share/jupyter/kernels/python3'
/private/var/tmp/sage-9.5-current/local/var/lib/sage/venv-python3.9.9/share/jupyter/kernels/python3
(base) ➜  ~ jupyter kernelspec install --user $(sage -sh -c 'ls -d $SAGE_VENV/share/jupyter/kernels/python3')
[InstallKernelSpec] Installed kernelspec python3 in /Users/XXXXXX/Library/Jupyter/kernels/python3
(base) ➜  ~ jupyter lab
```